# doing multiple things within a while loop perl

Tags: perl, join, while-loop, split

I have a relatively simple split/join script below.  The first part gets rid of a header row in my data  The second task is to split the \t delimited file and re-join in a template sequence of my choice.  After I re join the fields, can I do anything to any of the re joined individual fields?

When I run code like this, It will only do the first part of the script, the join.  Any suggestions?

**sample data**

```
Id  Name    date    amount  me/you  
1   jim 10/31/2014  78392   you
1   jim 10/31/2014  0   you
```

**desired output**

```
y,1,jim,2014-10-31,78392,yes
```

**Initial Code**

```
while (<>) {
    print and next if s/(^Pre-exisitng_Header_row*?\n|^$|^\s$)//; ##gets rid of header row/blanks
    my @flds = split /\t/; ##initiates split
    print join ",", @flds[5,1,2,3,4,5]; ##re joins to my liking.
}
```

**Desired Code**

```
use text::trim

        while (<>) {
            print and next if s/(^Pre-exisitng_Header_row*?\n|^$|^\s$)//;  ##gets rid of header/blanks.
            my @flds = split /\t/; ##initiates split
    trim for @flds[0,2..$#flds];
            print join ",", @flds[5,1,2,3,4,5]; ##re joins to my liking. to retain $[5] as is

           print if ($flds[4] != 0) ##after re joining, print if $[4] is not = to 0.
            if ($flds[3] =~ s/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/$3-$1-$2/; ##do a regex on [3]
    $flds[0] = "Y" if $flds[0] =~ /you/; ##do a substitution on [0]

            print @flds;
        }
```

**Further Explanation**

So basically what I want to do is split and re join my data to a certain template.  After it is in this template, I want to modify fields.  For example, you can see I want to print if and only if $[4] is not equal to 0.  Secondly I want to make sure the dates are in a yyyy-mm-dd format $[3].  Lastly I want to substitute $[0] from Yes to 'Y', all the while retaining the 'Yes'($[5]) in the last field of my new template.

Comment: `join` takes a list of strings and returns a string concatenated with the delimiter provided as expression. If you provide some sample data and explain what you need to do may be we can offer better solution

Comment: If that is your desired code, what is preventing you from using it? I don't understand your question.

Comment: @TLP I am having trouble with building the script and syntax

Comment: @JDE876 Your input does not contain `YES` or `y`. Where do you get that from? the `$flds[0]` should contain the `id`.

Comment: @jaypal i had meant to put you.  Also, $[5] is pushed over to $[0]  after print join ",", @flds[5,1,2,3,4,5];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something to get your started. You haven't mentioned where you get the `Y` or `Yes` keywords as your input data does not seem to have it. Also, it is not very clear if you want to print the header and blank lines as is or you want to remove them from output. I have gone with the latter but it should be an easy fix if you need the former. Also keep in mind that indices for array starts at `0`. So your first column is `array[0]` and not `array[1]`.

To answer your main questions regarding filtering lines where particular column is 0 and performing changes on some array elements, the following should give you some idea:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<DATA>) {
    next if /^\s+$|^\s*Id/;
    chomp;
    my @flds = split /\t/;
    next if $flds[3] eq 0;
    $flds[2] =~ s|(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})|$3-$1-$2|;
    my $pre = "y" if $flds[4] eq "you";
    print join (",", $pre //= "", @flds) , "\n";
}

__DATA__
Id      Name    date    amount  me/you


1       jim     10/31/2014      78392   you

1       jim     10/31/2014      0       you
```

#### Output:

```
y,1,jim,2014-10-31,78392,you
```

To add a prefix to the line, you just create a new variable and set it's value based on the value of the column. `//=` is defined-or operator. If the value of the variable is defined it will use that. Instead of `""` you can set a default value that it can use when it is not defined.

An alternate method to using regex is `split`. You can remove the last two lines from the code above and replace it with the following.

```
my @dates = split /\//, $flds[2];
print join (",", @flds[0..1], join ("-", @dates[2,0,1]), @flds[3..4]), "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do anything you want to members of @flds array.

```
print join ",", @flds[1,2,3,4,5];
```

does not modify @flds array